# Player sprite flickers when moving in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on 2D top-down shooter controller. Most of the time everything is ok but sometimes the sprites starts to flikker when controing it with mouse&keyboard. This only happens when both mouse&keyboard and a gamepad connected to my laptop. Also this never happen with the gamepad.

[Take a look at this for better understanding from this link](https://www.veed.io/view/36bc7bcf-2e64-4fc9-91ff-f107531b9f3f?panel=share)

This is my movement script

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float playerSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] float controllerDeadzone = 0.1f;
    [SerializeField] float gamepadRotationSmoothing = 1000f;
    [SerializeField] bool isGamepad;

    Rigidbody2D _rigidbody2D;
    PlayerInput playerInput;
    Controllers controllers;

    Vector2 movement;
    Vector2 aim;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
        controllers = new Controllers();
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        controllers.Enable();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        controllers.Disable();
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        HandleInput();
        HandleMovement();
        HandleRotation();
    }



    private void HandleInput()
    {
        movement = controllers.Controls.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        aim = controllers.Controls.Aim.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }

    private void HandleMovement()
    {
        Vector2 move = new Vector2(movement.x, movement.y);
        _rigidbody2D.velocity = move * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void HandleRotation()
    {
        Vector2 playerDirection = new Vector2(aim.x, aim.y);
        float rotationDegree = Mathf.Atan2(playerDirection.y, playerDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;

        if (isGamepad)
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(aim.x) > controllerDeadzone || Mathf.Abs(aim.y) > controllerDeadzone)
            {
                if (playerDirection.sqrMagnitude > 0.0f)
                {
                    Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotationDegree);
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, newRotation, gamepadRotationSmoothing * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Vector3 mouseWorldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(aim);
            Vector3 targetDirection = mouseWorldPosition - transform.position;
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(targetDirection.y, targetDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
        }
    }

    public void OnDeviceChange(PlayerInput pi)
    {
        isGamepad = pi.currentControlScheme.Equals("Gamepad") ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Would you please help me. this is making me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue here:

```
aim = controllers.Controls.Aim.ReadValue<Vector2>();
```

I assume you have one input action `Aim` with separate bindings for gamepad and mouse, hence those two inputs are completely different in nature despite the common value type (Vector2): the gamepad produces normalized vector [-1..1,-1..1], while the mouse produces screen-spaced vector [0..screenWidth,0..screenHeight]. If you're not disabling the gamepad binding (via handling it as a separate input action), you're getting 0,0 from gamepad when it is not active, that's why when you're not moving the mouse, your character looks at screent's 0,0 (bottom-left corner). So your issue is a consequence of not understanding the nature of Unity's Input System and attempting to over-optimise it, making one input action less than you needed.

Comment: But can you tell how to use TWO input action on one object?

Comment: Easy, just bring both to the same value space before merging them together. In your case you need to translate the mouse position to the directional vector, then add mouse-controlled and gamepad-controlled direction vectors and normalize the result.